# How to run monkey runner script?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

i am new to automating the android app.I heard that from Monkeyrunner we can automate..

I have seen some sample code..

How to run this? what is the extension for saving the code?

Do I need to connect device and run from the cmd prompt?

Please tell me as i am very new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run monkeyrunner from your development computer with the device connected or emulator running.

Like:

```
$ monkeyrunner myscript.mr
```

If you are using Linux or OS X you can use a she-bang including this as the first line in the script

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner
```

providing that monkeyrunner is in your PATH.

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to know that one thing. I am having an application (.apk) which has around 15 to 20 screens. I'll give you one example. Screen 1: Demo (on continue) Screen 2: Register personal details (onsubmit) Screen 3: Registerbilling details   (onsubmit) Screen 4: Success  (Ok) screen 5: Home screen. Every screen has package\screenname. So do i need to call all this or package only. Please guide me..

Comment: You monkeyrunner script can navigate through the screens (Activities), probably this is one of its main advantages against using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 test cases.

Comment: Thank you...Just confirming that I need to give Installpackage and startActivity itself is enough right? I need to give the path of the .apk file in the install package and startactivity is package/.demo                                                correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes, and once your demo activity started you can navigate through events

Comment: Hi, I am on screen 1. There is a button called "Register Now" is there on the screen. If I press any key, the button is not gaining focus. So i can not able to press the button using the keys to go to the subsequent pages. is there any way to select the button by any other way?

Comment: Use touch and screen coordinates

Comment: There's an example or monkeyrunner record/playback of events in http://www.amazon.com/Android-Application-Testing-Torres-Milano/dp/1849513503 chapter 5